# How do you compare observations having part of the key in common in SAS? (i.c. same family, different child)

Tags: sas

I have a data set like this

```
Family Student Age    Grade

1       Bob     10     4
1       Kris    12     5
1       Tracy   15     9
```

There are many other families in this data set. I need to find the siblings of the fifth grader, and create a new variable that contains the age difference between the sibling and the fifth grader. This is an activity that involves merging sets.

The set "school" contains all students and "fifthgraders" only has the fifth graders. I know how to merge them, but I'm stuck on finding their siblings and subtracting their ages.

```
data mergeStudents
   set school fifthgraders
   by student
run;
```

Comment: What should be the result if a family has one fourth grader, two fifth gragers and one sixth grager?

Answer (score 0):

Your code jut can't work, because

- you process data `by student`, not `by family`
- you read `fifthgraders` before their siblings

Second, I wonder why you did the effort to make a separate dataset with only the fifth graders. Apparently you don't know about the `where` clause in the dataset options.

A better solution would be

```
data mergeStudents;
    set shool (where =(Grade eq 5) in = grade_5)
        shool (where =(Grade ne 5) in = sibling);
    by Family;
    retain age_5;                   * do not nullify when reading the next observation ;
    if first.Family then age_5 = .; * forget the data about the previous family;
    if grade_5 then age_5 = Age;    * remember the age of the fifth grager in the family;
                                    * For a family with two fifth graders, this will be the last one in the dataset;
                                    * By sorting 'by Family age' first, you can force it to be the oldest one;
    if sibling then do;
        age_difference = age - age_5;
        output;                     * If you write an output statement in a dataset, ;
                                    * only observations for which the output statement is executed will be in the result;
    end;
run;
```